# Material UI tabs indicator gets stuck at the wrong place

Tags: material-ui

I'm trying to integrate the Material UI tabs (https://material-ui.com/demos/tabs/#centered), but I get a weird glitch on Safari 12.0.3, Chrome 73.0.36 and Chromium. The blue underline isn't shown at the right place until I click on one tab title:

[image: the blue line isn't at the right place]

The code is very simple and directly copied from the documentation:

https://gist.github.com/lcoenen/0f93bd2a2ae3fe9c76135d6b3d73d130

As you can see in the comments, I found a workaround by waiting a second, then setting the state to my default tab.

But is there a more elegant solution or should I create an issue on `material-ui` GitHub?

Comment: Please reproduce this in a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) and include it in your question. I am not seeing the behavior you describe..

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was related to a css used:
transform: scale(0.9);

if the scale is different from 1.0 then the tab indicator is at the wrong place...